# Performing update and delete operations inside if statement in sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm facing an issue in stored procedure while performing update and delete operations in sql server 2008.

Issue description :
Two out of 10 times records does not get updated in the  table(table1).

1. As the data (id) gets deleted from table2 it is not being referred as a foreign key in table1. When responseid is sent to the stored proc its value will be same in table1and table2.
2. So question here is  why update doesn't trigger sometimes but delete triggers everytime(data in table2 gets deleted) ?
3. Please suggest a way to eradicate this issue.

When tried with a sample application it works fine. Issue occurs  when there are multiple concurrent actions.

Here is the code

```
Declare @statusid int, @sent bit =1,@responseid (value is being  passed from. Net  code) 
If (@sent=1) 
Begin 
Declare @newtran bit 
Set  @newtran=0
If(@@trancount=0)
Begin
Set @newtran=1
Begin Tran 
End
If exists (select top 1 'x'  from table1 where responseid=@responseid) 
Begin 
Update table1 set statusid =@statusid where responseid =@responseid 
End 
Begin 
Delete from table2 where id =@responseid 
End 
If (@@ERROR <>0)
Begin 
If (@newtran =1 and @@TRANCOUNT>0)
Begin 
Set @newtran=0
Rollback tran 
End
Raiseerror ('failed ', 16,1) 
Return 600
End
End ---if ends here 
Else 
Begin

If exists (select top 1 'x'  from table1 where responseid=@responseid) 
Begin 
Update table1 set status =1 where responseid =@responseid 
End 
Begin 
Update table2 set count =count +1 where id =@responseid
End

--raising an error if error count <>0
Begin 

End
End 
If (@newtran=1and @@trancount >0) 
Begin 
--commit transaction 
End
```

Comment: Do you have `commit tran` in your code?

Comment: Yes at the end where commit transaction is written.. Commit tran exists in code.

Comment: You have a couple of `begin ... end` pairs that are not part of an `if` or `else` statement.  Is there meant to be a condition before those?  An example is the update of `table2` right before your "raising an error" comment.

Comment: Does the code work as expected when `table1` does *not* have a record where `responseid=@responseid`?

Comment: Yes Ann it is part of else. Condition would be like this If (@@ERROR <>0)

Comment: Table1 will always have the record (responseid)  as it is being inserted from table2(id is primary key in table2). As per project design, ID in table2 gets deleted. So haven't made the responseid in table1  as foreign key. But both (id in table2 and responseid in table1) will have same value.